# How browser handle transition effect when appending an element to page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my situation: when I click on a button, an element will be appended to body and do some transition effect. But nothing will happen if I just add a class, which has transition effect, right after `$('body').append(DOM string)`. In fact, I have found some solutions, like using setTimout; adding `.hide().show()` right after appending element; or adding `getComputedStyle(ele).display` after appending element. And my question is why the transition effect will be ran after I add these code? What's the different did browser do before and after I add there code?

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/7o310bhz/1/

In jsfiddle, I add getComputedStyle($html[0]).display to force reflow, which I am not sure whether it is correct. And in chrome timeline, I got following figures during parsing HTML:

with function getComputedStyle()
[image: transition effect with hack code]

without function getComputedStyle()
[image: transition effect without0 hack code]

After parsing HTML, I got following figures:

with function getComputedStyle()
[image]

without function getComputedStyle()
[image]

You can see there is a recalculation if I add the hack code. Also, the function add was executed, and it might means that the css class was added to DOM. Since the css class was added, why there is different between hack code is added or not?

I hope that I explain myself clear. Thanks!

Comment: Transition always work on a “from-state“ to “to-state” basis. With an element you just inserted into the DOM, there is no from-state for the CSS properties.

Comment: [some information](http://louisremi.com/2012/06/05/working-around-css-transitions-bugs-with-getcomputedstyle/#transition-display)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your reply. Could you please give me something more detail? Thanks...

Comment: @Chiu I have read this before, and do you have any information of the detail how browser handle transition effect? Thanks...